"Are you gonna get that?" "Get what?" Then a red phone rings
I think it's a film rather than a show.  I thought it was Tom Hanks, or somebody similar in appearance.
What is the film where a young guy can tell what's about to happen a few seconds into the future?  The scene I remember is something like the following:
The guy and a friend in a small room, like a dorm room.  Maybe they're not talking, just reading.  Or maybe they're talking about something and he interrupts.
"Are you gonna get that?" 
"Get what?" 
Then a red(?) phone between them(?) rings.

For some reason, I just love the subject line of this question. :) Hope we get an answer...

I think it's 80s or 90s

hey, how do you get your name upside-down like that?

@ShaneFinneran ʇno sıɥʇ ʞɔǝɥɔ Related question on stackoverflow

I recognise those lines but can't recall where from. Are you sure it's not a guy talking to an imaginary friend?

No, I'm not sure.  That's a possibility.

@ShaneFinneran I thought this was just some Unicode trick, nowadays nobody stops you from having a Korean or Hebrew name, so why not upside down Latin?

One show that uses a similar situation is Jekyll There'a a couple of scenes that play with the way that 

 Mr Hyde talks to Tom Jackman over the phone

In one particular scene

 Tom Jackman hears a phone ringing and asks another person if they're gong to get the phone, only to discover that the ringing is in his head

Although how anyone could forget watching such a memorable show like Jekyll is beyond me so it's maybe not the right answer.
That said the conversation with  an imaginary friend/alter ego is a common trope and adding a ringing phone to it has been done more than once.

Maybe Next with Nicolas Cage: he could predict future for several minutes.

The character played by Nicolas Cage was EXTREMELY careful about revealing his ability, until the last lengthy sequence when he was working to find the bomb.  This scene would have been out of character.  If a scene like this were to have happened, it would have gone more like "You need to answer that phone when it rings", as opposed to a response expecting it already.
